# Why Does Word Spacing Change Drastically When Using Libertine/Libertinus with the Various LaTeX Engines?

Tags: xetex, luatex, libertine, letterspacing, libertinus

I was just messing around in LaTeX with the `libertine` and `libertinus` packages, and noticed that switching from LaTeX to XeLaTex to LuaLaTeX all produced PDFs that were mostly the same length, except spacing in paragraphs slightly changed.

What is causing this? Is there any “correct” output?

At first I thought it had to do with the fact that `libertinus` switches from Type 1 encoding with pdfLaTeX and OpenType with XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX (not sure if `libertine` works in the same way), but even the outputs from XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX are different.

```
\documentclass{turabian-researchpaper}
\usepackage{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage{turabian-formatting}
\usepackage[pass,letterpaper]{geometry}
\usepackage{libertine} % or libertinus %

\begin{document}

Afraid of intimacy, we use technology to remove ourselves from the real world because we
believe more will listen to us when we are online. The internet and our phones become an
addiction that is hard to break. Although our technological habits change our personal
relationships for the worst, we continue the cycle of needing to text or post to social
media to feel validated. We have been blinded by our own emotions into thinking we need to
be online so we don't have to self-reflect, even though the situation is the opposite. This
is extremely harmful to our social skills, and we form habits that, before technology, most
would have called awkward or antisocial. We sit with our friends without interacting. We go
to cafés alone to do nothing but text. We spew hateful comments online through the barrier
of anonymity. However, the habit of checking your phone, posting to social media, and
commenting on content is extremely hard to break and needs patience and the willingness to
take breaks often. Technology does not need to always be wasting resources in the back of
your mind.
\footnote{Before you start an unrelated argument, I'm not actually anti-technology like
this might suggest. This was an essay written to appease an English teacher.}

\end{document}
```

Sorry if this isn't minimal enough. I couldn't find a way reproduce the issue without these words and packages.

This GIF demonstrates the differences between pdfLaTeX, XeLaTeX, and LuaLaTeX. [image: The different spacing produced by the different TeX engines.]

---

(Added by David Carlisle) test file just using article class but the same width and font settings as in the original example, it shows the same three output variants for pdf/xe/lua latex as the original but has less dependencies so a bit easier to trace (perhaps)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}


\usepackage{libertine} % or libertinus %

\setlength\textwidth{469.755pt}
\setlength\parindent{36.135pt}
\addtolength\oddsidemargin{-1cm}

\begin{document}

\typeout{\the\font}
\typeout{\the\fontdimen2\font} % space
\typeout{\the\fontdimen3\font} % stretch
\typeout{\the\fontdimen4\font} % shrink
\typeout{\the\fontdimen7\font} % punct

Afraid of intimacy, we use technology to remove ourselves from the real world because we
believe more will listen to us when we are online. The internet and our phones become an
addiction that is hard to break. Although our technological habits change our personal
relationships for the worst, we continue the cycle of needing to text or post to social
media to feel validated. We have been blinded by our own emotions into thinking we need to
be online so we don't have to self-reflect, even though the situation is the opposite. This
is extremely harmful to our social skills, and we form habits that, before technology, most
would have called awkward or antisocial. We sit with our friends without interacting. We go
to cafés alone to do nothing but text. We spew hateful comments online through the barrier
of anonymity. However, the habit of checking your phone, posting to social media, and
commenting on content is extremely hard to break and needs patience and the willingness to
take breaks often. Technology does not need to always be wasting resources in the back of
your mind.


\end{document}
```

Comment: unrelated but you shouldn't have that linebreak before the footnote or you could get a linebreak before the footnote marker

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yeah, I made a lot of changes while hastily writing that code to make it easier to read. Originially the footnote was right at the end of the last sentence. Thanks, though. Didn't realize that could happen.

Comment: Another unrelated note on your initial example using the `turabian-formatting` package: you don't need to (nor should you) specify `\usepackage{turabian-formatting}`. Simply loading the `turabian-researchpaper` document class will create a turabian-formatted research paper.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you add

```
\typeout{\the\font}
\typeout{\the\fontdimen2\font} %space
\typeout{\the\fontdimen3\font} %stretch
\typeout{\the\fontdimen4\font} % shrink
\typeout{\the\fontdimen7\font} % punct
```

after `\begin{document}` then you will find

pdftex

```
\OT1/LinuxLibertineT-TLF/m/n/12 
3.0pt
1.5pt
0.99959pt
0.5004pt
```

xetex

```
\TU/LinLibertine(0)/m/n/12 
3.0pt
1.5pt
1.0pt
1.0pt
```

luatex

```
\TU/LinLibertine(0)/m/n/12 
3.0pt
1.5pt
1.0pt
1.0pt
```

Note that fontdimen7 (extra space after punctuation) ends up twice as large in the OpenType font as in the tfm metrics used by pdftex.  I note the libertinus font suport had an update yesterday in texlive this is with the latest version of that package (and a development build of luatex 1.09) running over texlive 2018.

So the big difference between pdftex and the others is not surprising, it's harder to see an obvious reason for a difference between luatex and xetex other than luatex explicitly documents that it uses a variant hyphenation algorithm that doesn't always choose the same points even using the same patterns.

Comment: hmm actually hyphenation points chosen for luatex and xetex are same but line breaks are still different, I may look again later and add to this answer.

Comment: Something to do with microtypography? XeTeX is more limited there ...

Comment: Without the extra packages in OP's example, XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX with `linertinus` give same output (to the eye) which is almost same as PDFLaTeX except for the footnote marker going to next line with XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX.

Comment: @jfbu I may try later to remove the extra packages (but set the same textwidth and font sizes as they set up) I expect then article class would give the same as the image in the question

Comment: I was lacking class and packages in my install, but now I added them, so brief look at file list of compilation log dispels my suspicion about some special things (the turabian.cls does `\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}` but the turabian-researchpaper.cls has nothing of this type afaict)

Comment: @jfbu I added an `article` class example to the question

Comment: I tested your `article` class example with `libertine` on a non-updated since July at least TL2018 on a Linux box, and xelatex/lualatex give same output, no difference between them.

Comment: but this uses `/usr/share/fonts/opentype/linux-libertine/LinLibertine_R.otf`...

Comment: @jfbu does the last line start with `to` in both? If so luatex has changed, it now starts with `always`

Comment: it did, but I was updating my TL2018 in the background and now LuaTeX last line does not have the `to`. The lualatex log still ends with `</usr/share/fonts/opentype/linux-libertine/LinLibertine_R.otf>` whereas xelatex seems to only use the texlive tree font.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82877/discussion-between-david-carlisle-and-jfbu).

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you for your answer! I actually didn't know you could measure out the fonts being used (but of course you can, this is TeX). I knew going in there was a difference font metrics between pdfTeX and the others, since the `libertinus` and `libertine` packages use different versions for the different type encoding. Although, I didn't expect the difference to be so big. Thanks for the help and the thoughtful answer.

Comment: @MarkBoltz it's quite possible that the difference isn't intended to be that big, if I can work out why lualatex has changed the line breaking from xetex (using the same fonts) I may ask the font maintainers if the type1 and OTF metrics are supposed to be more similar....